# templated template specialization?

Tags: c++, template-specialization

Say I want to write a wrapper for 2 or more classes that do the same things with different implementations and their interfaces have different function names. Depending on the context I would choose the one or the other, but I want to be able to easily switch them out. SO I write a wrapper with template specialization. Ok good. Now however I encountered a problem. My 2 classes are template classes...

If they were normal classes I could write code like this:

```
class A1
{
public:
    int f()
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

class A2
{
public:
    int g()
    {
        return 1;
    }
};


namespace detail
{
    template <class T> int h(T& t)  // general case
    {
        std::cout << "general" << "\n";
        return t.h();
    }
    template <> int h<A1>(A1& a1)     // case for A1
    {
        std::cout << "A1" << "\n";
        return a1.f();
    }
    template <> int h<A2>(A2& a2)     // case for A2
    {
        std::cout << "A2" << "\n";
        return a2.g();
    }
}

template <class T>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper(T& t) : t(t) {}

    int operator()()
    {
        return detail::h<T>(t);
    }

    T& t;
};
```

However, how would I need to modify that code to make it run for tempalted versions of `A1` and `A2`? The best I came up with was this (does not compile):

```
template <class T>
class A1
{
public:
    int f()
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

template <class T>
class A2
{
public:
    int g()
    {
        return 1;
    }
};


namespace detail
{
    template <class T, class U> int h(T<U>& t)    // general case
    {
        return t.h();
    }
    template <> int h<A1<U>>(A1<U>& a1)     // case for A1
    {
        return a1.f();
    }
    template <> int h<A2<U>>(A2<U>& a1)     // case for A2
    {
        return a1.f();
    }
}

template <class T, class U>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper(T<U>& t) : t(t) {}

    int operator()()
    {
        return detail::h<T,U>(t);
    }

    T<U>& t;
};
```

So, I somehow need to template the template specializations, which sounds like a contradiction.

## edit

Ok.. trying to make the overload solution work, but I don't really get it...

```
template <template <typename> class T, class  U>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper(T<U>& t) : t(t) {}

    template <template <typename> class T, typename U>
    int h(T<U>& t)    // general case
    {
        return t.h();
    }

    template <typename U>
    int h(A1<U>& a1)     // case for A1
    {
        return a1.f();
    }
    template <typename U>
    int h(A2<U>& a2)     // case for A2
    {
        return a2.g();
    }

    T<U>& t;
};
```

Comment: Do not use the same template parameter names for the `class` and the method, this is not allow in C++ (you should get warnings for that). Use, e.g. `template <typename V> int h(A1<V>& a1) { ... }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefer overload to template specialisation:

```
template <template <typename> class T, typename U>
int h(T<U>& t)    // general case
{
    return t.h();
}

template <typename T>
int h(A1<T>& a1)     // case for A1
{
    return a1.f();
}
template <typename T>
int h(A2<T>& a2)     // case for A2
{
    return a2.g();
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but can you extend that snippet a little? I don't really understand where this is meant to be put and what template parameters my class now needs. I have tried several ways to make this work but none did. See my edit.

Comment: @lotolmencre I took your original template functions from the namespace detail and changed them to overloads. Thought, you'd realise that and take above overloads back to the namespce details. Within the operator() you had in the original version of the Wrapper class, the correct overload would have been selected according to the Wrapper's template parameters.